# Heading background image that extends to the edges and top of the page with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a simple page where the all the content (`<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<p>`, etc.) is contained within a `<div>`, in order to have the same width.

I like the way the body text looks and want to keep it that way, but I'd like to add a background image to the heading. It should start from the very top of the page (and window, in my case) and end at the baseline of the last line of the heading itself, while also extending in width from the left side of the window to its right. In the following image I illustrated the desired layout. Below it, I've drawn the html hierarchy that I've attempted.

[image]

In fact, I've already tried creating a child of `<h1>` with

```
width: 100vw;
position: relative;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%);
```

but:

1. Since the page has `z-index: -1;`, for some weird bug I can't click on links with relative positioning
2. I'd prefer not to use `vw` unites because of browser support.
3. I still can't manage to extend the background to the top.

The font size of `<h1>` and its margins are defined in pixels, as you see, but the page still behaves dynamically because as I resize the window, the number of lines of `<h1>` increases.

**HTML**

```
<div class="page">
   <h1>Heading</h1>
   <h2>Section 1</h2>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0px;
}

.page {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 70ch;
    padding: 50px 5%;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: -1;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 26px;
}

p {margin-bottom: 24px;}
```

**[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fu2038vb/2/)**

Comment: Most of the time people seperate the width constraints into its own class and just use it multiple times. That way you put your h1 inside of a div with a class of container, then you put THAT in the div that you want to have a full width background, then the rest of the page falls after it. like this: https://jsfiddle.net/fu2038vb/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions:

Separate the h1 and the rest of the body in two different divs. Apply the background to the first div.

```
<div class="background-here">
<div class="page">
   <h1>Heading</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page">
   <h2>Section 1</h2>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

Or you could just apply the background to the body and use `background-repeat: repeat-x` or `bakcground-size: cover`. But it depends on how the image was designed.